# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'remove')?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an ecommerce as a project and I'm trying to finish up the function to delete items from the cart. I think I'm close to making it work but I get the "Uncaught TypeError". I understand why this error happens, but I haven't been able to recognize how to fix it. I think the problem is in the line "let fila = document.querySelector(`${products.id}`)", but I don't get why ${products.id} is a problem.

Any help would be amazing. Thanks.

```
function retrieveCart() 
{   
    let cart =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    let container = document.querySelector("#cartItems")
        carrito.forEach(products => { 
            let fila = `<div class="itemBoxCart p-4" id=${products.id}>
                            <div class="card h-100 shadow">
                                <div class="card-body p-4">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <h5>${products.name}</h5>
                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center small text-warning mb-2">
                                        <div class="bi-star-fill"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span class="text-muted text-decoration-line-through"></span>
                                        ${products.price}
                                        <button id="deleteItem" class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">Delete</button>    
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>`
                        container.innerHTML += fila
        });
}
retrieveCart() 

// DELETE ITEMS

const deleteItems = () => {

let buttonDelete = document.querySelectorAll("#deleteItem");
        
    for (const deleteItem of buttonDelete) {
        deleteItem.addEventListener("click", ()=> { 
            const newCart = cart.filter(productos => productos.id != deleteItem.id);
            let aDelete = cart.indexOf(newCart,0)
            cart.splice(aDelete,1)
            localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(newCart)); 
            let fila = document.querySelector(`${products.id}`)
            fila.remove()
        });  
    }
}
deleteItems();
```

Comment: Where is `products.id` defined? It seems `products` is out of scope where the error occurs. What is it supposed to be? If it’s a selector that matches nothing, then `querySelector` will return `null`.

Comment: When the error happens, what value does `products.id` have?  What element do you expect `querySelector` to find for it and why?

Comment: In the `deleteItems` function, where do you declare and define `cart` ?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#deleteItem");` You have multiple `id`s with the same name? Is that supposed to be `document.querySelectorAll(".deleteItem");` a classname?

Comment: "#deleteItem" is an id that all the delete buttons have, and then the items themselves have a specific id each. With "#deleteItem" I'm identifying the button, and with `${products.id}` I'm trying to specify the item in the cart that I'm trying to delete.